# Python / Django app: a wine list with filter menu. Where should the filter logic go? Frontend or Backend?

Tags: python, django, rest, filter, view

I have created a wine list app and I am starting to question my design. First off if you look at the views.py snippet below, you see a simple solution to send all active Wine objects. But the real question is, how do I create a filter side menu? I like using views for all of the logic, but to me it seems that having a sidebar, especially with ajax would need to be quite a bit of front end code.

Here is [a New Egg filter example.](http://www.newegg.com/Processors-Mobile/SubCategory/ID-759?Tid=8599)

I am looking for direction on how to create such a side filter menu using Django. Is this going to be something that is driven by the front end mainly? Can this be driven by views? Is Django Rest framework something I should check out?

```
def wine_list(request):
    wines = Wine.active.all()
    return render(request, 'wine/wine_list.html', {'wines': wines})
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution to your problem is using django forms, so your filter box will be a normal django form, user will select items from those forms then click on submit button

in your view method you use submitted data to generate a queryset and render template for user. (check out [django-filters](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io) module that might be helpful (this solution handles everything on server side)

another solution is using rest - you create an api end point for wine `Eg /api/wines/`, then in website, when user chooses some filters you send a request (with jquery, ...) get new data and put them in result table, without reloading the whole page (this approach needs some client side work) - (django-filters might be helpful here too)

based on your project requirements you can choose on of these approaches